Fast algorithm to obtain an orthogonal vector to a set of vectors
When I ask this question I am usually suggested to do things like computing the SVD decomposition of the matrix formed by the vectors. SVD decompositions are very computationally expensive.
I am also doing this in the context of a krylov sequence, so I suspect there has to be a much easier way to generate orthogonal vectors.
This is one potential algorithm that works but might take a long time to converge:
let v = random vector;
let m = [v];
for i in 0..k
{
  let w = A * v;
  orthogonalize w with respect to m;

  while w < epsilon
  {
     w = vector of random samples of a uniform distribution;
     orthogonalize w with respect to m;
  }

  append v to m
     
}

The issue here is that, as the dimension of the problem gets larger, the probability of getting a vector with an orthogonal component to the other vectors becomes smaller and smaller.
I was wondering if there is something faster than SVD and less dumb that this random sampling approach.

The probability remains $100%$ in perfect arithmetic. Note that counterintuitively a $100%$ probability does not mean that an event where $n$ random vectors are linearly dependent cannot occur, it's just that the measure of such an event/set is zero. In practice you could just pick $n$ random vectors and orthonormalize and the probability that they span $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be $100%$. If the orthonormalization fails at some step just pick a new random vector for this step. You can use Gram-Schmidt and variants for your purposes with Gaussian distributed random vectors.

I assume you will find this interesting: https://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node106.html

The normal approach for orthogonalization in Krylov methods is to use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.  Any good textbook discussing Krylov methods should cover Gram-Schmidt.  (Yousef Saad's "Iterative methods for sparse linear systems" is an excellent reference on the subject.)
In practice, you'll want to use Modified Gram-Schmidt (MGS) or Classical Gram-Schmidt with Reorthogonalization (CGSR) for numerical stability reasons.  But, Classical Gram-Schmidt (CGS) shows the general idea of these methods.  Given a basis $M$ and the new vector $w$, CGS orthogonalizes the new vector by:

$x = M^T w$
$u = w - M x$
$v = u / \lVert u \rVert $

In general, I can't think of any context where SVD is needed for simply orthogonalizing vectors.  QR factorization will work just fine at a significantly lower cost (although pivoting or QLP might be needed if the vectors are dependent).

The issue here is that, as the dimension of the problem gets larger, the probability of getting a vector with an orthogonal component to the other vectors becomes smaller and smaller.

Normally, Krylov methods should only be used to build a basis that's significantly smaller than the original matrix.  So, a random vector will almost always have component orthogonal to your basis.  If you want to build an $n \times n$ basis (or even an $n \times \tfrac{n}{10}$ basis), you should use a direct method, not a Krylov method.

This doesn't fully address the problem. The motivating case for this is the identity matrix. In that case the krylov sequence is just the vector. This makes it hard to create a subset of the eigenvectors of the identity matrix.

If you are solving a system of equations with a Krylov space method, you just stop when the residual is 0.  Otherwise, you orthogonalize the residual vector and move on.  However, that doesn’t help if you’re just given a set of orthogonal vectors and ask to complete an orthogonal basis.    You could do this by successively trying the columns of the identity matrix and skipping any columns that are already in the range of your starting set of orthogonal vectors.

@Makogan Could you clarify what part of the answer needs more clarification?  Gram-Schmidt can be used in both of the "orthogonalize w with respect to m;" lines in your pseudo-code.

@BrianBorchers I was thinking of something like that, too, but then I noticed that OP doesn't want to find a vector such that $|w - \operatorname{proj}(w)| > 0$, they want one such that $|w - \operatorname{proj}(w)| > \varepsilon$. So we would need to find a quantitative bound to claim that one of the first $i+1$ columns of the identity matrix suffices.

@NeilLindquist Think of the krylov sequence generated by the identity matrix used to compute the eigenvectors of the matrix. Gram Schmidt applied to the krylov sequence can only generate one vector. You need further work to create  new vectors to span the entire space of eigenvectors.

@Makogan Gram-Schmidt can orthogonalize any vector, w, regardless of whether it comes from the Krylov subspace or the random sampling

@NeilLindquist Yes, the problem is coming up with the starting vector to orthogonalize. If I give you N linearly orthonormal vectors, then the goal is to create a new n+1 vectors, completely from scratch, such that the n+1th vector is also orthonormal to the rest.

If n is small relative to the dimension of the vector space, taking a random vector will work fine.  If n is large, just use a direct method to compute the eigenvectors.
